# URI Online Judge - 1026 - To Carry or not to Carry - Wrong answer (100%)

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to solve this problem in URL Online Judge: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1026

Using Python, my answer was:

```
v1, v2 = input().split()

v1, v2 = int(v1), int(v2)

res = v1 ^ v2

print(res)
```

I get as a result: "Wrong answer (100%)". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "In each input line there will be a pair of integer separated by a single space. Input ends at EOF." You only read one line.

Comment: Hi @Ryan. The input() ends when the user press the Return key. So, I think it is ending on EOF. The input is automatically done by URI Online Judge. Am I right?

Comment: EOF is "end of file". There can be multiple lines of input. You have to process each one.

Comment: You're right, @Ryan. I'll post the beginning of the right answer now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As @Ryan answered, I had to read multiple lines of input, so, the beginning of the code is:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    v1, v2 = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
    # The rest of the code here.
```

Thanks for the help @Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
try:
    list1 = input().split()
    X, Y = list1
    print(int(X) ^ int(Y))
except:
    break
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.